# Canvas to img with src blob

Tags: javascript, canvas, png, blob

I'm creating a PNG file from a canvas, but before I want to display the canvas as an img element, using a blob as the src of the img. What I tried so far:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
//Get data from canvas
img_b64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
//Create PNG
png = img_b64.split(',')[1];
//Create new img
img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = img_b64;
//Append img to document
//Save png
```

This works, but instead of `img_b64` I want a blob to be the src of the img, like this:

```
//Create blob from new PNG
blob = new Blob([window.atob(png)], { type: 'image/png', encoding: 'utf-8' });
//Create new img with blob as src
img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
//Append img to document
//Save png
```

The above code only shows me an empty img. Is there a way to do this or do I have to create the png file first and afterwards create a blob for it?

Comment: looking at `blob = new Blob([window.atob(png)]...`, how is `png` in that statement defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found an solution using the answer to this question: [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata). Using the `dataURItoBlob` function my code is:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
//Get data from canvas
img_b64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
//Create blob from DataURL
blob = dataURItoBlob(img_b64)
img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
//Insert image
```

dataURItoBlob function:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to drop in and say that in the meantime `<canvas>` got a [`toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method that might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

With [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) this should be easy to solve from IE>=10.

```js
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
    img.src =  URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  });
```